# How to plot dices, that change with the result

Tags: r, plot, dice

I am trying to do a yahtzee game in R, amd I would like to show the dice on the plot part of R. like this :
[image]

I have this function how simulate a dice roll

```
rolls_the_dice <- function(X1 = 5){if(X1 <= 5){sample(1:6, X1, replace = TRUE)}
```

But I don't know how to display the score the way I described. I have two main ideas:

First:

```
plot(c(0, 200), c(0, 170), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes= F, main = "")
rect(xleft = 30, xright = 80, ybottom = 0, ytop = 50)
rect(xleft = 0, xright = 50, ybottom = 100, ytop = 150)
rect(xleft = 70, xright = 120, ybottom = 100, ytop = 150)
rect(xleft = 140, xright = 190, ybottom = 100, ytop = 150)
rect(xleft = 120, xright = 170, ybottom = 0, ytop = 50)
```

That plot 5 rectangles, and then I have to find a way to put points in it giving the result

Second :

```
rect(xleft = 0, xright = 20, ybottom = 0, ytop = 20)
points(x= 10, y= 10, col="black", pch=19)
```

This is the face one of a dice. This idea is to create one plot per dice face, and then to pick them up giving the result. But here I don´t know how to store them.
If somebody could tell me what is the best (or even just the feasable) idea.

Answer (score 4):

there's a package for that ;-)

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidydice)
roll_dice(times = 5, rounds = 1) %>% plot_dice()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of doing it in base R using lists...

```
#your function
rolls_the_dice <- function(X1 = 5){if(X1 <= 5){sample(1:6, X1, replace = TRUE)}}

#a list of x-y coordinates of the corners of the five dice
rects <- list(c(30, 0), c(0, 100), c(70, 100), c(140, 100), c(120, 0))

#a list of list(x, y) coordinates of the dots for numbers 1-6
dots <- list(list(0, 0), 
             list(c(-1, 1), c(-1, 1)), 
             list(c(-1, 0, 1), c(-1, 0, 1)),
             list(c(-1, -1, 1, 1), c(-1, 1, -1, 1)), 
             list(c(-1, -1, 0, 1, 1), c(-1, 1, 0, -1, 1)),
             list(c(-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1), c(-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1)))
              
#a function to plot a dice and a number
plot_face <- function(rects, dots){
    rect(xleft = rects[1], xright = rects[1] + 50, 
         ybottom = rects[2], ytop = rects[2] + 50)
    points(x = rects[1] + 25 + 15 * dots[[1]], 
           y = rects[2] + 25 + 15 * dots[[2]], col = "black", pch = 19)
    }
     
#plot a blank area (note asp=1 to keep the dice square)                   
plot(c(0, 200), c(0, 170), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     axes= F, main = "", asp = 1)

#plot the five dice and five random numbers
mapply(plot_face, rects, dots[rolls_the_dice()])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be also interesting for you: the 'TeachingDemos' package provides a "dice" function code https://github.com/cran/TeachingDemos

```
#install.packages("TeachingDemos")
library(TeachingDemos)
dice(5,1, plot.it=TRUE)
```

[image]